# Error in file: on line 4: Importing test library 'Selenium2library' failed: ModuleNotFoundEr ror: No module named 'Selenium2library'

Tags: python, automation, robotframework, ui-automation

I'm new to RobotFrameWork and I'm currently setting up everything on my machine to be able to use this tool for some of my test scenarios.

The issue that I'm getting is the following:

```
(venv) C:\Users\aharo\PycharmProjects\Automation>robot Salesforce/Login.robot
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\aharo\PycharmProjects\Automation\Salesforce\Login.robot' on line 4: Importing test library 'Selenium2library' failed: ModuleNotFoundEr
ror: No module named 'Selenium2library'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  None
```

My currentrobot file is set up like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2library

*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
LoginTest
    open browser                https://test.salesforce.com/    chrome
    input text  id:username [my_username]
    input text  id:password [my_password]
    click element   xpath: //input[@id='Login']
    clsoe browser


*** Keywords ***
```

However, I'm not sure where I'm making a mistake. I'm currently using windows 10, and I already installed the plugin and the right packages.

What else should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong case for `Selenium2library` - it is named `Selenium2Library` (capital "L"). Also, that library is very old and not supported. You should upgrade to `SeleniumLibrary`